# Function changes the value of parameter unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I wrote a function `calcNewtonPath` with 4 parameters as below. However when i call it, the function changes the value of parameter `matA` unexpectedly and i can't understand why.

```
function calcNewtonPath(matA,matB,m,n){
  let temp = matA.slice()  //i tried this to prevent the unexpected change but it didn't work
  for(let i=0;i<m;i++){
    temp[i].push(-matB[i])
  }
  return matrix.solve(temp,m,n)
}
```

The function `solve` also changes the value of `temp` too! But it's a bit complicated so i think i will not put the code here.
Can anyone help me about this?

Comment: You should add code to your question that we can debug as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:**

.slice() will just do a shallow copy.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

That means for example:

```
const a = [[1,2,3]]
const b = slice.a();

b[0][1] = 4;
```

**a** array will also be changed.

**a** will be [[1,4,3]] as well as **b**;

One easy solution would be to make a deep copy of an array:

```
const deepCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array));
```